# How to separate dataset into the same fixed size of groups?

Tags: python

I am wondering how to separate all elements in a list into several groups with the same size of length.

For example, there is a list containing 12 elements: `A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]`.
Then, 4 adjacent elements in `A` are put into a sublist.
Finally, the results would be like: `[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this handy one by using more_itertools:

It's to group elements from iterable into *fixed-length groups of length* n (in this case is 4)

```
>>> from more_itertools import grouper
>>> list(grouper(lst, 3))
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9), (10, 11, 12)]
>>> list(grouper(lst, 4))
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (5, 6, 7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12)]

# Or strictly list of groups:
>>> groups = [list(x) for x in grouper(lst, 4) ]
>>> groups
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Alternatively, you can use pure Python (w/o 3rd party lib):

```
n = 4 
gps = [list(lst[i*n:i*n+n])  for i in range(n-1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Daniel Hao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73015857/2745495), here is a generalization for n groups:

```
from more_itertools import grouper

# could be any list
A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

def divide_list(input_list, n):

    # check for adequate group size
    if n > len(input_list):
        print('group size bigger than original list.')
        return None

    return [list(x) for x in grouper(input_list, n)]
```

Testing:

```
test = divide_list(A, 5)
print(test)

# output:
# [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, None, None]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A division with rest and slice approach.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

blk_size = 5

A_chunked = [A[blk_size*i:blk_size*(i+1)] for i in range(len(A)//blk_size)]

# if not possible to group all elements chunk of the same size
if r:=len(A) % blk_size:
    A_chunked.append(A[-r:])

print(A_chunked)
#[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

It the chunks need to be *all* of the same size then either truncate the iteration (hence the conditional part is not required) or compensate the rest with some default values, here `None`,

```
if r:=len(A) % blk_size:
    A_chunked.append(A[-r:] + [None]*(blk_size - r))
```